# Change JsonSerializerSettings within the API controller

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating a base WebAPI controller that most of my controllers will inherent from.  This controller will need to modify the JsonSerializerSettings by adding a particular Json Contract resolver.

It's important that I do this within the controller itself because at the time of the Contract creation I need access to the HttpRequest as well as an injected service.

Currently I'm simply overriding the Ok(object value) method:

```
  public override OkObjectResult Ok(object value)
  {
     var resolver = new TranslationContractResolver(_translationService, language);

     // serialize the object, and in doing so will translate all translatable properties.
     string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        value,
        Formatting.None,
        new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = resolver });

     // now, deserialize back so we can respect content requests (XML, etc).
     Type type = value.GetType();
     var deserializedBack = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type);

   return base.Ok(deserializedBack);
```

This does work, but I'm sure I'm taking a performance hit.

I'd like to add the contract resolver within the OnActionExecuting method, but I don't know how to get access to the JsonOptions configuration in a proper way.  I have been able to obtain the IServiceProvider from the HttpContext, then grab the IOptions(JsonOptions) from the provider, and directly overwrite the SerializationSettings. But this seems very hacky and it seems to retain that setting for responses in other controllers thereafter.

Comment: Are you looking to change that in all controllers, or specific controllers, or specific actions?